# Remote Server SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Tags: php, mysql, centos, cpanel

When using php to connect to a remote MySQL database (say `999.999.999.999`) from a server running on a different IP (say `888.888.888.888`), I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Here is what I've tried or looked into:

- On the remote server, I have allowed connections from the "local server" (`888.888.888.88`), but that hasn't helped.
- Some answers suggest changing the connection details from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, but this is not relevant to me as we are connecting to a remote database.
- I restarted the server (CentOS with `cPanel`) several times with no luck.

Any idea?

Comment: It's clearly not reaching the server at all. If it was a permission issue you'd get a response. Firewall?

Comment: perhaps this is the problem you are telling. permission or firewall issue. how can i check the permission?

Comment: Please read my comment again. I don't think it's a permission issue—it that was the case MySQL would reply with something like *ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'joe'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*, not just let the connection open until it times out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1 - SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] A connection attempt failed.. - When attempting to connect from Local to remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914770/laravel-5-1-sqlstatehy000-2002-a-connection-attempt-failed-when-attemp)

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting this question because I ran into a similar problem on `cPanel` and none of the answers I found solved it.

There is a progression of three steps to resolve this issue. For me, the third was critical.

**1. Credentials**

We'll assume you already have the correct credentials to access the database. These can be tested:

- locally on the database if you have direct access.
- remotely, from an IP that is **not** the one giving you trouble (your CentOS server). For instance, you can use programs such as HeidiSQL (Win) or Sequel Pro (OSX) as a sanity check.

You could also run a php script like the following one both from the troublesome origin server and from another server. If only your server refuses to connect, you know you don't have a credentials issue.

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=999.999.999.999;dbname=Database_Name_Goes_Here;charset=utf8',
            'User_Goes_Here', 'Password_Goes_Here',
            array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
            );
    echo "We connected.";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print($e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

**2. Remote Access: Allowing your IP**

Most of the answers point out that in the remote server, you must allow connections from your IP. You have already done this.

For everyone else, if you are also using `cPanel` like the OP, you can add the IP in the `Remote MySQL` section of `cPanel`.

**3. Firewall**

This was the missing ingredient for me in the answers I found. After all, isn't there a chance that the error message might be correct, i.e., that the connection simply timed out?

This points to outside connections being disabled from your server. I investigated if there were any parameters in `php.ini` that could conflict, then turned at the firewall, which provided the answer.

I don't know which firewall you're using. Here's what to do for those using the csf firewall, which is common on cPanel / WHM installations. Assuming you have SSH access, enter something like this, where the IP is that of the remote database server:

`csf -a 999.999.999.999 'allow connection to XYZ database server'`

- If you have a different firewall, see the documentation.
- If you have neither ssh nor WHM (or equivalent) access, ask your web host to unblock the remote IP for you.

Comment: +upvote. I have solved this and dont remember how it was. But this will help once the issue found again

Comment: @RejoanulAlam I also did a thorough reformatting of your question to make it more useful to others in the future, hope you like that. By the way, can you tell me if you were on cPanel, and were you using php? Cheers!

Comment: Yes it was cPanel + php & I had no access on WHM this is why it was necessary then