# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed.. - When attempting to connect from Local to remote server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1, hosting

env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY= ...........

DB_HOST=srv3.linuxisrael.co.il
DB_DATABASE= name_of_my_database
DB_USERNAME=moti_winkler
DB_PASSWORD=1234567890

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Routes.php :

```
use App\User;

Route::get('/', function(){
    User::create(['first_name' => 'moti']);
    return view('welcome');
});
```

The error i get :

> **PDOException in** Connector.php line 55:
>
> **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A
> connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
> respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
> because connected host has failed to respond.**

My problem is that:

I'm trying to connect from my computer - to my remote MySQL server

And I don't understand why it doesn't work ?

What should I do to connect ?

What am I missing ?

I am using Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hardly a surprise. The mysql socket is rarely if ever left open for connections from the public facing interface. usually mysql port (3306) can only be accessed from the private network interface.

Even if the socket was open, there are so many things that that go wrong including firewalls getting in the way and simple timeouts.

Answer (score -1):

Use SSH tunnel to connect the remote database.

More about SSH tunnel and some examples here: http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html