# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user '<username>'@'ip-10-61-196-73.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)")

Tags: mysql, django, database, pythonanywhere

I understand that similar questions have been asked before, but none of the solutions seem to work.

I built my django project with pythonanywhere, and initially I just used a sqlite3 database following a tangowithdjango tutorial. Now that I actually want to get a database working online, I'm getting all kinds of errors.

I created a new database following https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingMySQL/, and I entered the following into settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ofekih$theofekfoundationdb',
        'USER': 'ofekih',
        'PASSWORD': '<my_sql_password>',
        'HOST': 'ofekih.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
    }
}
```

Then, I opened a console online and ran: python manage.py syncdb, which gave me a long error message ending with:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'ofekih'@'ip-10-61-196-73.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)")

I then checked my access, opening an online console at my mysql database and running: show grants; This returned the table including the line:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `ofekih$theofekfoundationdb`.* TO 'ofekih'@'%'
```

Which is very weird because the previous error message said that access was denied for a user that matches that same statement.

Meanwhile, back in my local computer where I'm developing the code, running python manage.py runserver with the new database in the settings.py, it waits for a long time before another error message appears ending with:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ofekih.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com' (110)")

I can't help but feeling that I'm overlooking something very simple, and it would be very much appreciated if someone more skilled than me could help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This answer will explain why you are unable to connect to the remote mysql server from your local dev machine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36915614/267540 . Do you have shell access on the production server? if so try usinig the mysql console on it to connect to the server with the same credentials you have used in your django settings

Comment: @e4c5, thanks for your reply!
How could I use the mysql console to connect with the server?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my password was just wrong. Make sure not to use backslashes () to try to escape characters in the string.