# Can not connect to mysql remote server using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cloud9

I install a phpmyadmin application in a cloud9 workspace.
The I configure it to connect a mysql server running in another cloud9 workspace.
To configure it I just add the following lines on the phpmyadmin configuration file (/var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php):

```
i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '[my IP]:3306'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'madeiraod';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '[my password]';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

I just follow the instructions in [here](http://sforsuresh.in/access-remote-mysql-server-using-local-phpmyadmin/)

When I open phpmyadmin I can not access the remote server and I get always in the top of the application the string that I added to the configuration file:

> i++; $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '[my IP]:3306';
>   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'madeiraod';
>   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '[my password]';
>   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

Why the configuration appears in the beginning of the phpMyAdmin instead of being processed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] A connection attempt failed.. - When attempting to connect from Local to remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914770/sqlstatehy000-2002-a-connection-attempt-failed-when-attempting-to-connec)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was missing the php tags:

```
<%p 
  i++;
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '[my IP]:3306'; 
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'madeiraod';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '[my password]';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
%>
```